# Binding modes of a protein on a planar surface graphene

Tags: proteins, binding-sites

Can a protein have different binding modes on a flat even surface like graphene? For a surface like Graphene oxide I can understand, since it has several oxygenated groups on its surface that makes it easier for a protein to have different binding modes, but what for a homogenous aromatic surface like graphene?

Answer (score 2):

Proteins tend to denature on hydrophobic surfaces, which "changes" the binding modes in that it abolishes them completely. I found a [study on BSA binding affinity when adsorbed to reduced graphene oxide](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0008622320304243) (rGO), which should have very similar behavior to graphene itself.

> The biochemical functionality of adsorbed BSA was investigated through the interaction with its anti-BSA antibody counterpart. BSA on GO can retain its binding sites while, in contrast, a denatured ad-layer of BSA forms on the rGO followed by further binding of active BSA molecules, depending on the concentration of the protein.